# .form-control is not showing

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio, intellisense

I can not find form-control in bootstrap css. It's not showing as hint when writing code in visual studio. I'm writing it anyway, I think maybe somehow it is not showing but its killing me.
I also linked all reference files to my html document.

```
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" />
```

and my select statement :

```
<select id="treatmentefielde" name="treatmentfield" ng-model="findTreatment" class="form-control">
<option value="Inpatient-Rehab">LInpatient Rehab</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Bootstrap [dropdowns](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns) explicitly don't use `select` element for styling purposes so I wouldn't expect form-control to inherit to it correctly anyway

Comment: Its working in your code snippet.

Comment: i also tried it on inpu type text but it also wont work ?

Comment: Nitin no its not working bro.

Comment: What version of Bootstrap do you use?

Comment: version 2.3.2 @makshh

Comment: So there is your problem. There is no form-control class in Bootstrap 2.

Comment: then which version should i use ? @makshh

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: @ShababQaisar, does your issue is solved or not? If not, you can update your current issue in here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you used the bootstrap v2.3.2 and there is no class form-control, you can check [this document](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html).

Have a look at [this](http://getbootstrap.com/css/), to use the class form-control and select element, you need to install or reference the bootstrap 3 or higher version.

In VS 2015, if you create a ASP.NET web application and choose Empty template, to get the latest bootstrap v3.3.7, you can right click project name under Solution Explorer and choose Manage Nuget Packages… and click ‘Browse’ and search bootstrap, then install it. After that, you can add a new HTML page, then find there is the intellisense for class control-form like the following screenshot:
[image]

For other templates like Web Forms, MVC when you created web application, you will find the bootstrap default added during the creation which the version is v3.0.0, you can directly use the class form-control.